# How to Validate Widget Input

Tags: widgets, forms

I have been working with widgets and widgets API.

I see that the widget form is rendered and processed through widget() function.   I can write validation logic inside the widget() function. I will do a isset($_POST) check and write the form handling logic in it.

Something like this:

```
function widget($args){

extract($args);

is isset(){$_POST['fieldname']

{  // form processing logic  }


// echo HTML Form

}
```

I would like to separate the form processing logic from the widget function. How can I achieve this? Is there a standard way for doing this?

Comment: The `update` method inside your widget class should deal with validating and sanitizing the data, the `widget` method should deal with preparing that data for display.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Widget API then declare your widget as a class which extends `WP_Widget` class and there you can define an `upadte` function where you can do your validation, [**`the codex as a nice example of doing just that`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Example).

Comment: I am using the Widget API.  As far as I understand , the update function handles the widget settings.. i.e the input entered via the admin interface.  I am developing a newsletter widget where a user can enter his email and subscribe to the blog. I handle the subscription logic , email-validation etc. inside the widget() function and it makes the code messy. Is there a way to separate subscription logic, validation from the widget() function?

Comment: A simply create a new function inside that class and call it.

Comment: Thanks.. will try that. Seems like Wordpress does not provide a standard way of doing this. Have been searching for it but couldn't find anything.